# Redux 'connect' function with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm writing a React Native app using Redux and Typescript. I've been looking at other people's code (which I can't share verbatim), and when they use the `connect` function, it looks like this:

```
export default connect<a, b, c, d>(
  state => ({
  ...
  }),
  dispatch => bindActionCreators({
  ...
  }, dispatch)
)(<Component name>)
```

Can anyone explain what the use of the `a, b, c, d` parameters is? I know this involves Typescript generics, but can anyone give me a deeper understanding of how `connect` uses these?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the details of connect method with ite interfaces:

```
<TStateProps = {}, TDispatchProps = {}, TOwnProps = {}, State = {}>(
        mapStateToProps: MapStateToPropsParam<TStateProps, TOwnProps, State>,
        mapDispatchToProps: MapDispatchToPropsParam<TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>
    ): InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<TStateProps & TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>;
```

For further details visit [typescript-and-react-redux-connect](http://www.masteringreactjs.com/2018/04/23/making-sense-of-typescript-and-react-redux-connect/)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this it is syntactically very verbose.

Generics on connect are meant to be inferred not passed through statically (although there are some exceptions.

bindActionCreators is also no longer neccessary as anything passes as the second arguments object values will automatically be bound with dispatch

I.E the above code can be simplified to...

```
const mapStateToProps(state: IGlobalState) => {
     return {
        // add things you want from your state here.
     }

} // if you don't want anything from your state you can pass null.

export const withState = connect(mapStateToProps, {addTodo: TodoActions.add})(ComponentName)

export const withNoState = connect(null, {addTodo: TodoActions.add})(ComponentName)
export const withNeither = connect()(ComponentName) // at first glance looks useless but this will actually give you access to 'dispatch' inside your component.
```